# Meaning of "positively dangerous"?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

I don't get why dangerous could be positive. Is the author trying to indicate something?

Comment: *positively* is used here to mean *absolutely, altogether, completely*  which is hyperbole for emphasizing how dangerous it is.

Comment: You mean positively is more intense than absolutely?

Comment: If you do a search for the meaning of "positively", you'd see what Jim said as well as the meaning of "without a doubt".  I'm voting to close since no research was done for this question.

Comment: No, it really means it's *certain*, there's no doubt about whether it is dangerous or not.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't mean "in a positive way" in this case. A better definition is:

> With certainty; so as to leave no room for doubt
>
> [AS SUBMODIFIER] Used to emphasize that something is the case, even though it may seem surprising or unlikely

*Source:* [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/positively)

Comment: Yes - in creative writing and some journalism (and web content), it is quite often used this way, to emphasise a significant (but maybe infrequent) feature of the thing or event being described, usually in association with a mild adjective then a more intense adjective than normal. So: "The current in the river wasn't just strong today, it was positively dangerous." or "The stadium wasn't just crowded for the concert, it was positively packed.".