# Meaning of "positively skeptical"?

Tags: phrases

I read the term "positively skeptical" in the following paragraph:

> (News about a product released by some company)
>
> (the company) has a
> lot more work to do compared with the competitior to deliver a
> product that is outside of (some country). I'm not even sure people
> need it. I hope it works. I can't wait to see it and to try it. But
> until I do, I (remain) **positively skeptical**."'

My question is, does/can "positively" convey any traces of the following:

1. "I'm certainly skeptical; my viewpoint will not shift from being skeptical to wishfully thinking the product will succeed, until I have seen it and tried it."
2. "I remain a positive attitude and am looking forward to positive signs that this product succeeds, despite the lack of such signs as of now. I wish it can succeed."
3. Something else, maybe a combination of #1 and #2.

Some background research:

1. In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290799/meaning-of-positively-dangerous), "positively" meant "certainly, without a doubt", similar to #1 above.
2. In [this article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/the-power-of-positive-ske_b_8635), "positive skepticism" is used to make the point that skepticism has positive attributes, in response to another article that focuses on the negative attributes. Here the word "positive" does not seem to be related to the author's attitude towards the object of skepticism but rather skepticism itself.
3. The [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/positively) defines "positively" as "absolutely, certainly", similar to #1 above.

Thanks a lot and sorry if I missed anything.

Comment: You have an apparent contradiction in terms, positive and negative. But Elton John used the effect in Rocket Man: "Mars ain't the kind of place to raise your kids. In fact it's **cold as hell**."

Comment: It's interpretation 1 in this case. The same structure is used in expressions like "I'm positively outraged by the fact that the builders have left my house in such a mess". There is nothing positive about the situation or the sense of outrage but the statement says that the speaker's sense of outrage is very much on the positive end of the scale of outrage rather than being low down on that scale.